# How to detect whether a webm file is audio or video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mime-types, webm

I am building an uploader with ReactJS. When a user uploads a video or audio file, I take the MIME files and register the type (video or audio) to display icons later on.

I have a problem when they upload audio files with the extension `webm` (music.webm) and the MIME type is `video/webm`, so I register it as video, when in fact I should register it as audio.

I have tried to decode the video and find some codec to be sure that there is no video using [blob.text()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/text), but I can't find the information, or I don't know where to look.

I know it is possible, because the player knows the difference.

How can I detect whether a webm file is audio or video?

Comment: No experience myself but you could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/music-metadata-browser, it claims to have support for webm.

Comment: Doesn't have data for everything (I tried their example with react too and doesn't support a lot of extensions)

Answer (score 0):

You can read it from the ebml header.

1. Install ts-ebml (https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml).
2. Add following code:

```
import * as ebml from 'ts-ebml';

export const getMediaStreamType = async (buf: ArrayBuffer) => {

    const decoder = new ebml.Decoder();
    const ebmlElms = decoder.decode(buf);
    const els = ebmlElms.filter(d => d.name === "TrackType");
    return {
        video: els.some((e: any) => e.value == 1),
        audio: els.some((e: any) => e.value == 2),
    };

}
```